# Can a character-level Seq2Seq setup learn to perfectly reconstruct structured data like name strings?

Tags: natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, sequence-modeling

If not perfect, how well can they do? For example, if I give the Seq2Seq setup a name it did not see in the training process, can it output the same name without error?

Example

```
name = "Will Smith"
output = DecoderRNN(EncoderRNN(name))
can_this_be_true = name == output
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give it a name, it will probably be **almost** perfect model, as the number of hidden units are definitely enough to store the raw data of a name. However as a neural network it will still not be perfect. There may also be serious overfitting if you do this. A Seq2Seq model have way more parameters than necessary to just "remembers" all the possible names, as names variants are not a lot.